Young loner male meets a girl and possibly kills her, psychological thriller?
From what I remember:
Main character is a young mentally troubled male working at a small insurance/telemarketing type company.  Has one friend who is a co-worker (his boss I think?), lives alone, he greatly enjoys jazz music and painting.
Pretty girl starts working there, she starts talking to him, they connect.  She finds sketches of other girls in his bedroom, infers that he knew all these girls previously and possibly killed them.  They struggle and I think the scene fades to credits?
I cannot remember the name of this for the life of me, and I haven't seen either person in any other films.

There are several movies with this plot. Please provide more detail: Approximate year? B&W\color? Is it American? Do you remember any other detail?

Added this info to the question.

Goodness me, we are trigger happy with the close button! Come on, this is perfectly on topic!

I retracted my close-vote since the question was improved.

This is almost the exact plot of "Chosen Prey", a novel by John Sandford. However, that was not one of the two Prey books that have been made into movies (Mind Prey and Certain Prey).

Uh-oh, don't trust young men who listen to Jazz music!

Sounds like you're looking for Spiral from 2007. If you are, let me know and I'll close it as a duplicate.

yep thats exactly what I was looking for!

I think you're looking for this one -  Spiral (2007). The storyline matches your description.
Mason might be the painter you're talking about,

Mason (Moore) is a quiet, introspective young man doing phone work for an insurance company, painting vivid portraits of women in his spare time.

and the story goes like this,

Throughout the whole story, it is apparent that Mason has an obsessive concern with his paintings and his “rules.”  Near the end, Amber discovers that Mason has known many women and has done almost identical paintings of them.  However, when she breaks Mason’s rule that she never looks at his sketches until the paintings are complete, he breaks down, and violently kills her.

Try this to get more information about this movie.
Here is the trailer of Spiral which matches most of your description.
